# Am I overcomplicating this method for determining if a Type implements an Interface?

Tags: c#, .net

Seems to produce expected results, but is there a better way?

```
        public static bool IsImplementationOf(Type type, Type iface)
        {
            if (Type.GetType(iface.ToString()).IsAssignableFrom(Type.GetType(type.ToString())))
            {
                return true;
            }

            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I am aware of the `is` operator but it doesn't work for me (in the method calling this one) since I am working with types assigned to a variable of type `Type`.

So `(typeof(myParam) is IMyInteface)` where `myParam` is a passed-in variable of type `Type` does not produce the right results (I think it's null) - since `typeof` expects a literal type - but `Type.GetType(myParam.ToString())` does.

Being new to OOP, I'm not sure if something has gone way over my head here. For further context, this test is used by a factory pattern to instantiate an object of the requested type via the right constructor but only if it implements certain interfaces.

Comment: How about `iface.IsAssignableFrom(type)`?

Comment: yes: replace `if(somethingThatEvaluatesToABoolean) { return true; } else { return false;}` with `return somethingThatEvaluatesToABoolean;`

Comment: How are you planning to call this method?

Comment: @Franz good point, should have seen that one

Comment: @Sweeper, the difficulty there is iface is a variable with a type, not a literal type.

Comment: @yrebrac I know. Did you _try_ what I said? For what case did it not work? What error did it produce? `Type.GetType(type.ToString())` just gives you back `type` if `type` is in the current assembly...

Answer (score 5):

You don't need your `IsImplementationOf` method at all, just use `Type.IsAssignableFrom` directly - just note the reversed-order of the subjects:

```
// Instead of:
if( IsImplementationOf( typeOfTheObjectInstance, typeOfTheInterface ) )
{
    // ...
}

// Do this:
if( typeOfTheInterface.IsAssignableFrom( typeOfTheObjectInstance ) )
{
    // ...
}
```

A fuller example:

```
interface IFoo { }

class Foo : IFoo { }

class Bar { }

//

Type ifooType = typeof(IFoo);
Type fooType  = typeof(Foo);
Type barType  = typeof(Bar);

// "Does 'fooType' implement 'IFoo'?" - yes!
if( ifooType.IsAssignableFrom( fooType ) ) {

}

// "Does 'barType' implement 'IFoo'?" - no, it does not
if( ifooType.IsAssignableFrom( barType ) ) {

}
```

---

> Being new to OOP, I'm not sure if something has gone way over my head here

Using reflection is not OOP. Reflection is a subversion of OOP.

If you do OOP "correctly" (according to the academics) you'll never need to use reflection - however in practice, the mythical OOP as it was originally defined in the 1980s is nearly impossible to attain and has limited benefits - that's why languages like C#, Java, and C++ are better described as being hybrid-paradigm languages - and purists will argue that Smalltalk and Objective-C are much better examples of OOP languages anyway.